# docker: recomendations on docker image format and layers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to structure my docker image so it is small but I am not sure if this is a good pattern for keeping each layer small. Open for any recomendations?

The main points I am curious about are relating to the "update" and "rm" with each layer. Should i be doing it this way or is there a better method.

```
# our base image
FROM ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND "noninteractive apt-get autoremove"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales \
    && locale-gen en_AU.UTF-8 \
    && dpkg-reconfigure locales \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV LANG en_AU.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_AU.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_AU.UTF-8
ENV LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8
ENV TZ="Australia/Adelaide"

# networking and routing tools
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y \
    net-tools telnet dnsutils inetutils-traceroute \
    curl jq \
    postgresql redis-tools mongodb-clients \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# node libs for test scripts
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Some suggestions: inherit from a specific tag of your base-image (e.g. `ubuntu:18.04)`; [merge your 3 RUN commands into one](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#env) (comments like `# node libs` can still be inserted between the lines if you like); merge your ENV declaration similarly to RUN (`ENV <key>=<value> ...`). Generally your Dockerfile looks good, especially that you cleanup at the end of each RUN command.

Comment: The "networking and routing tools" section at a glance is likely totally irrelevant to your application (`telnet`?) and I'd delete it entirely.  Consider replacing the whole thing with `FROM node:8`.

Comment: @fab so are you thinking there is no value in the layers separating the libs for test scripts from the core tools?

Comment: @donkeyx there might be cases where you'd want to do it for optimized caching, but in your case this it not the case: All those libs are just external dependencies which end up in your image eventually, so there's no benefit in having them in different layers. You might consider using docker-[multistage-builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to keep your test-deps out of your runtime-image though.